# Regex capture a word under specific conditions

Tags: c#, regex, match, cpu-word

Hello i have another regex problem..

i have following text

```
Liquor
Liquor-Aussehen klar entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.
+
Leukozyten im Liquor < 5 /µl 6 entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.
Erythrozyten im Liquor 0 /µl 1 entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.
Mononukleäre Zellen i.L. - 100 % 0 entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.
Polymorphkernige Zell i. 0 % + 100 entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.
+ + - -
Glucose im Liquor 40 - 70 mg/dl 71 80 66 26 26 66
Lactat im Liquor < 2.1 mmol/l 1.5 1.6 1.7 ++ 5.1 ++ 5.1 1.7
Gesamt-Eiweiß im Liquor mg/dl entf. entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.
IgA im Liquor < 5 mg/l 3.20 4.01 ++ 17.00 + 10.00 + 10.00 ++ 17.00
IgG im Liquor < 34 mg/l + 53.00 + 57.60 + 97.00 + 65.00 + 65.00 + 97.00
IgM im Liquor < 1.34 mg/l + 1.40 + 1.82 ++ 8.00 ++ 4.50 ++ 4.50 ++ 8.00
Albumin im Liquor < 350 mg/l + 460.0 + 441.0 + 980.0 + 720.0 + 720.0 + 980.0
```

the first Liquor is the head of the document.. And i need to find this one. 
But if i look just for "Liquor" the regex will match the ones in Glucose im Liquor f.e. as well..

i build following regex because i think this negative lookahead will do the thing but

```
Liquor(?!-\s?[a-zA-Z<>+-0-9]?)
```

still matches the other ones.. 
How can i exclude the Liquors that doesnt stand alone. 
Liquors that can be followed by a number, letter or lower than or higher than signs shouldn be matched..

Is there any Solution?

Comment: Use end string ancor `$` maybe? Would that suffice? > `^Liquor$`

Comment: Please share your related code to see how you handle the string. What are trying to achieve? I doubt you want to extract a known word.

Comment: Do you only want the head/title or the word "Liqour" which stands alone in a line?

Comment: yes, i want only the standalone word "Liquor", but the text can also look like i have shown in my other comment : 

"\nLiquor\nLiquor-Aussehen klar entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.\n+\nLeukozyten im Liquor[...]"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `Liquor` line, then match `^Liquor$`

Or if you want a line that ends with `Liquor` then use `Liquor$`

BTW, in all your other lines with Liquor (except the 2nd one), the word is followed by a space (this is why the negative lookahead returns true every time : `-` cannot match a space)

Comment: Yea that worked for the text above but in furher test and other textes i recognized that the regex didnt match the word when it looks like this

"\nLiquor\nLiquor-Aussehen klar entf. entf. entf. entf. entf.\n+\nLeukozyten im Liquor[...]"

where i need the first Liquor